# Add progressbar using glide

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a image gallery where the images are loaded from url and takes some time to load the image. SO I would like to progressbar. I tries to add an animation drawable and adding a placeholder, but in that case the loader image takes large space as that of the image. I would want the placeholder to be displayed as a normal progress bar.

**Code:**

**dot_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"/>
</selector>
```

**progress_animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:gravity="center">
    <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading"
                     android:padding="50dp"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I also tried by adding listener to glide, but no luck here as I cant access viewholder element inside listener class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Com.Bumptech.Glide;
using Com.Bumptech.Glide.Load.Resource.Drawable;
using Provenance.Models;
using Com.Bumptech.Glide.Request;
using Com.Bumptech.Glide.Request.Target;
using Com.Bumptech.Glide.Load;
using Com.Bumptech.Glide.Load.Engine;
using Java.Lang;

namespace Provenance.Android.Adapters
{
    public class ViewDocumentAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, IRequestListener
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        public List<DocumentImageURL> _items;
        private readonly Activity _context;
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
        #endregion

        public ViewDocumentAdapter(Activity activity, IEnumerable<DocumentImageURL> images)
        {
            _items = images.ToList();
            _context = activity;
        }

        void OnClick(int position)
        {
            if (ItemClick != null)
            {
                ItemClick(this, position);
            }
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.imageListItem, parent, false);
            DocumentViewHolder vh = new DocumentViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            DocumentViewHolder vh = holder as DocumentViewHolder;
            var chemical = _items[position];
            // vh.imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.logo);//_items[position]);
            DrawableTransitionOptions options = new DrawableTransitionOptions();
            options.CrossFade();
            //.transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            Glide.With(_context)
                        .Load(_items[position].Thumbnail)
                        .Apply(new Com.Bumptech.Glide.Request.RequestOptions()
                            .Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.progress_animation)//Android.Resource.Drawable.ic_document)
                            .Error(Resource.Drawable.ic_exclaimation)
                            .FitCenter())
                        .Transition(options)
                        .Listener(this)
                        //.Apply(RequestOptions.CircleCropTransform())
                        .Into(vh.imageView);
        }

        public DocumentImageURL getSelectItem(int position)
        {
            return _items[position];
        }

        public bool OnLoadFailed(GlideException p0, Java.Lang.Object p1, ITarget p2, bool p3)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnResourceReady(Java.Lang.Object p0, Java.Lang.Object p1, ITarget p2, DataSource p3, bool p4)
        {
            ///cant access progressbar<----
            return false;
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return _items.Count; }
        }

        public class DocumentViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public ImageView imageView { get; set; }
            public ProgressBar progress { get; set; }
            // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
            public DocumentViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener) : base(itemView)
            {
                imageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
                progress = itemView.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progress);
                itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.Position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better option.

Comment: Add a position property (an index) of type int to ViewHolder to find the corresponding ViewHolder object through this position. Maintain the map in the adapter, where key is the position in the adapter, and value is the position of the holder, so that the position corresponding to the ViewHolder object can be obtained according to the position of the item to be refreshed. At the same time, all ViewHolders are saved to a collection. Generally, the number of viewholders created by the adapter is the maximum number of items displayed at the same time plus 2, and then is reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by passing `DocumentViewHolder` parameter to listener class:

**Modified code:**

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    DocumentViewHolder vh = holder as DocumentViewHolder;
    var chemical = _items[position];
    DrawableTransitionOptions options = new DrawableTransitionOptions();
    options.CrossFade();
    Glide.With(_context)
        .Load(_items[position].Thumbnail)
        .Apply(new Com.Bumptech.Glide.Request.RequestOptions()
            .Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.progress_animation)//Android.Resource.Drawable.ic_document)
            .Error(Resource.Drawable.ic_exclaimation)
            .FitCenter())
        .Transition(options)
        .Listener(new listenerImage(vh))
        .Into(vh.imageView);
}

internal class listenerImage : Java.Lang.Object,IRequestListener
{
    private DocumentViewHolder holder;

    public listenerImage(DocumentViewHolder holder)
    {
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    public bool OnLoadFailed(GlideException p0, Java.Lang.Object p1, ITarget p2, bool p3)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnResourceReady(Java.Lang.Object p0, Java.Lang.Object p1, ITarget p2, DataSource p3, bool p4)
    {
        holder.progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        return false;
    }
}
```